# How to use paging next in the new Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the new Facebook PHP SDK. I trying to get the name of all the pages liked by the user. But it is only returning me 25 of them. As far as I know if I have to get all of them then I will have to use the "next link" in the "paging" returned by the "graphObject".

But I have no idea how to use it. And if I am wrong then can you point out how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm doing this in php in order to get all the likes:

```
public function getLikes () {

    $likes = array();

    // Custom method! Get the session however you like
    $session = $this->getSession();

    $request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/me/likes'
    );

    do {
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $some_likes = $graphObject->getProperty('data')->asArray();
        $likes = array_merge($likes, $some_likes);
    } while ($request = $response->getRequestForNextPage());

    return $likes;
}
```

As you can see, the getRequestForNextPage() method is the key.

Answer (score 0):

I have reached a weird thing about the getRequestForNextPage() method,
I am trying to solve my problem for about 8 hours right now.
The problem is, that this method is returning different data then just clicking on the "next" link when opened in browser, it is just moving the until date for about two days, so many of data i want to get are duplicated, and even more, the request for next page starts cycling after that, so I again get data for the first request, my code is almost the same as the one above. Anyone else had this problem?